# Python regex - getting timestamp from string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7

I have a string which takes form similar to these:

```
A: u'As of 9:30 AM EDT. 
B: u'As of 10:15 AM EDT. 
C: u'As of 4:30 PM EDT.
```

Here is my code:

```
import re

pat= u'[0-9]?[1-9]{1}:[0-9]{2}\s[A|P]M'
rxc = re.compile(pat)

s = grok_date_string()

matches = re.findall(rxc, s)
```

My code fails to match B. Why?!

Comment: Because of the `[1-9]`. Use `(?:1[0-2]|[0-9]):[0-9]{2}\s[AP]M`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [link](https://regex101.com/r/nX5uA4/1) to the example.

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s(?:AM|PM))')
results = re.findall(pat, YOUR_STRING)
# matches HH:MM AM/PM
```

Answer (score 0):

The second digit of the hours may not be 0, only 1-9. Thus your code would be matching `11:15 AM` but not `10:15 AM`.

Replace the regex with

```
'[0-9]?[0-9]{1}:[0-9]{2}\s[A|P]M'
```

and it should work.

You can even simplify it further using

```
'[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}\s[A|P]M'
```

Comment: I will accept this answer when I can (7 minutes remaining). Silly mistake on my part. Sometimes I embarrass myself SMDH

Comment: This will match even `99:78 |M` substring if it finds one.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the second digit, that is restricted by your regex to the range of 1-9, which will not match your second example.

A possible regex could be: `[01]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\s[AP]M`

Note: you don't need to put the `|` character between square brackets (as you did to match AM/PM); all the characters within the square brackets are automatically OR'd.

Comment: Excuse me, but `17:00 AM` is not valid, Iis it? `[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\s[AP]M` will also match `29:00 AM`.

Comment: Depends on how you interpret the question. It will extract the time stamps from the given stings in the question. The more complex the regex, the lower the performance as well.

Comment: Performance is not the key with such patterns based on negated character classes that only match short strings. Precision is more important.

Comment: Again, depends on your point of view. Let's leave it at that, shall we?